# How to make sure the header is not "floating"?

Tags: header-footer

In a `classicthesis` document with `twopages`, I have chapters, and they appear in the header.
However for one of them, the header over few pages is vertically shifted. All the other pages have the chapter correctly aligned.

1. why ?
2. how to prevent this floating from happening ?

I'm using this setup:

```
\usepackage[beramono, pdfspacing, dottedtoc]{classicthesis}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}} % Header for even pages (twoside)
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection~#1}} % Header on odd pages
\lehead
{
    \mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern 1em\color{black} \vline}
    \color{black}\hspace{0.5em}\rightmark\hfil}
} % The header style
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
```

Using:

```
\chapter{D'un style d'enseignement \`a Vincennes... Ch\^atelet, Deleuze, Lyotard}
```

I get:

[image]

For repro:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside, headinclude, footinclude]{book}

\usepackage[beramono, pdfspacing, dottedtoc ]{classicthesis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem, varioref, bm, url, epigraph, libertine, float, afterpage}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}} % The header for all pages (oneside) or for even pages (twoside)
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection~#1}} % Uncomment when using the twoside option - this modifies the header on odd pages
\lehead
{
    \mbox{\llap{\small\thepage\kern 1em\color{black} \vline} \color{black}\hspace{0.5em}\rightmark\hfil}
} % The header style
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\title{Book title}
\date{}
\author{}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\newpage\phantom{.}
{\centering \maketitle}
\pagestyle{plain}
\tableofcontents{}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\chapter{D'un style d'enseignement \`a Vincennes\ldots Ch\^atelet, Deleuze, Lyotard}
\lipsum[2-10]
\lipsum[2-10]
\end{document}
```

In the repro code, we can see the problem in the last two pages.

The log is telling what happened, but I don't see how to correct the source:

```
Chapter 1. [1] Underfull \vbox (badness 1152) has occurred while \output is active Overfull \hbox (25.01971pt too wide) has occurred while \output is active [][] 

Package scrlayer-scrpage Warning: \headheight to low.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                At least 37.8001pt needed,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                but only 15.95pt found.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll enlarge \headheight, for further
(scrlayer-scrpage)                processing, but you should do this yourself,
(scrlayer-scrpage)                e.g., setting typearea's option
(scrlayer-scrpage)                `headheight=37.8001pt'.
(scrlayer-scrpage)                I'll also decrease \topmargin on input line 31.
```

Comment: do you get over/underfull hbox message? I would guess it is forcing a linebreak in the header and leaving a blank line but with no example posted hard to guess.

Comment: Your header is definitely too wide.  You could use the "short title" option  :`\section[short title]{long title}`.  You could put `\rightmark` inside a `\parbox{\dimexpr \textwidth-0.5em}{\rightmark}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I'm using the content of \chapter in the header, but there is no [short title] option for it. For the \rightmark and \parbox option, where do you put it ?

Comment: The fact that the new empty line appears only in the header of even pages is also a mystery. Can't I prevent that so the title size and position matches that on the odd pages ?

Comment: Please, show a compilable example from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: @egreg Good point. OP updated.

Comment: Book class and titlesec (loaded by classicthesis) support the [short title] option for \chapter.  But not for \chapter*.  If you really want to overhang the right side, use \rlap\rightmark in \lehead, and possibly \llap\headmark in \rohead.